# Image replaces input element

Tags: jquery, triggers, image-upload

I want to make the "image uploader script". I do not want to use input element. When red image is clicked, system window will appear, and you can choose image file. But it does not work in IE 9.

jQuery code :

```
// this part of code does not work in IE9
$('img').click(
    function(){
      $('#photoimg').trigger('click');
});

// this works fine
$('#photoimg').live('change', function(){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
      target: '#preview',
      success: function() {
          alert('IMG was loaded.');
      } 
    }).submit();
});
```

HTML code:

```
<img id="icon" src="http://ynternet.sk/test2/close_1.jpg">

<form id="imageform" method="post" action='upload_file.php'>
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'> </div>
```

Example :

```
 http://ynternet.sk/test_4/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is trying to access an element with id "myfile" but your markup has no such element.

It worked for me in both IE9 and Chrome when I changed the id of the file input to match what was in the code (though obviously you could change the JS to match the html):

```
<input type="file" name="photoimg" id="myfile" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ytcXF/

Comment: I'm sorry, it was just copy/paste mistake. Just please see new edit and example.

http://ynternet.sk/test_4/

Comment: Script is working on jsfiddle, but not uploading image on server. Becouse on jsfiddle you can not upload image, so you can not see the problem.

Comment: The comments in your code (in the question) say that the img click is the part that doesn't work but that the change event handler and upload "works fine" - are you saying that actually it is the other way around? You could try `$('#photoimg').change(...` instead of `$('#photoimg').live('change'...` - not sure about IE9, but I'm pretty sure in older IE the change event didn't bubble, which would mean it wouldn't work with `.live()`.